# Update data in database using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table in my database. Field of table are describe below.

```
ID | NAME | QUALIFICATION 
 1 | ABC  | Phd
 2 | XYZ  | MBA
 3 | ADS  | MBA
```

Now my problem is related to update QUALIFICATION record. Suppose if I update record of QUALIFICATION, it should be append new value to existing value.

For example, I am going to update record of id=1. Now I update "QUALIFICATION" `MCA` then it should add `MCA`  to the existing record `Phd`, separated with comma. Output will looks like below.

```
ID | NAME | QUALIFICATION 
 1 | ABC  | Phd,MCA
 2 | XYZ  | MBA
 3 | ADS  | MBA
```

When "QUALIFICATION" is null then the update should not be add comma before MCA.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a bad database design never store the data as comma separated string, this will make things messy in future.

You should think of normalizing the table something as for the `student` your table should look like

```
- id primary key auto_incremented
- name 
- other columns related to student
```

Then another table as `student_qualification`

```
- id primary key auto_incremented
- id_student ( id from student table)
- qualification
```

So for each student you can add as many qualification as possible to this table and can easily do add/edit/delete data

You can later easily retrieve data using simple joining the table.

Comment: To be properly normalized there should be another table QUALIFICATION, with STUDENT_QUALIFICATION as an intersection table.  However, I don't think a discussion of normalization constitutes an answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

May you can try this

```
 update employee set qualification = qualification || ',MCA' where id = 1
```

the above will work in oracle

**EDIT:**

Then you can have the case statement with it

```
   update employee set qualification = case when qualification is null then
                                     'MCA' else qualification || ',MCA' end where id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But when "QUALIFICATION" is null then it should not be add coma before MCA.

Comment: 0 rows affected. ANd your first answer is also display 0 rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

> first u have to select your existing value of Qualification column
>   that u want to update
>
> Using

```
select qualification from  tb_name where id = 1
```

> Using above query u will get your qualification column value
>
> suppose in

`$qulification`

> Now update that row using

```
update set tb_name set qualification = '".$qualification."."your new value" where id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test for NULL in the SET clause, and use concatenation to format the string appropriately.

```
update student
set qualification = concat(if (qualification is not null
                               , concat( qualification, ',')
                               , '' )
                           , 'MBA')
where id = 1;
```

Here is a [working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b1cb/1) (which also demonstrates behaviour with a NULL qualification).

---

I agree with [@Abhik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164632/146325) that this is a bad design *for this specific data*, and normalization is the better approach for the use case you provide  However, there are other use cases where doing this sort of update would be perfectly valid so the question is worthy of a proper answer..

Comment: APC I need to append new data with existing. Your code replace existing. If the field have null value then don't add coma before new value. If the field have any value then add new value with coma before new value. thanks for consideration.

Comment: SQL Fiddle appears to be down at the moment but please try this revised solution and see whether it works for you